# Is it possible to find an entry 3 entries before a specific entry without relying on cursors and IDs?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm currently working on finding a specific data entry that is 3rd entry before a specific other entry. My main problem is that the table has no `id` field and only a `date` field. Else I would have been able to find a good solution for that.

Example:
The table has  the fields: LogDate, LogEntry.

I'm expecting the following data:

```
2015-01-01 07:10:10 This is the 1st line I want
2015-01-01 07:11:10 Nothing to report
2015-01-01 07:11:13 Nothing to report
2015-01-01 07:15:10 Tag
2015-01-01 07:17:10 Nothing to report
2015-01-01 07:20:10 Nothing to report
2015-01-01 07:30:10 Nothing to report
2015-01-01 07:32:10 This is the 2nd line I want
2015-01-01 07:35:10 Nothing to report
2015-01-01 07:40:10 Nothing to report
2015-01-01 07:41:10 Tag
2015-01-01 07:43:10 Nothing to report
2015-01-01 07:44:10 Nothing to report
2015-01-01 07:45:10 Nothing to report
2015-01-01 07:54:10 Nothing to report
2015-01-01 07:55:10 This is the 3rd.....
.....
```

The expected result is:

```
This is the 1st line I want
This is the 2nd line I want
```

The sql I'm using to get the Tag lines is:

```
SELECT LogEntry
    From myTable 
    where LogEntry = 'Tag' and LogDate >= '2015-01-01 05:00:00' 
    order by LogDate ASC
```

This gets me the "Tag" entries. What I'm not sure about is if it is possible to get the entries which are on the 3rd line above each without using a cursor / stored procedure or a C# program or ... .

*Note: SQL Server version is 2012*

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: This seems to me [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Yes it is possible with windowed functions easily.

Comment: I fail to understand how your query is getting you the 'Tag' entries.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos tnx just saw it myself that I added the date restriction but not the entry restriction.

Comment: 'This is the 1st line I want' is two rows before the following 'Tag' and 'This is the 2nd line I want' is three rows before the following 'Tag'. So different rules apply here? Or is this just a typo?

Comment: was a typo corrected (sry there had to manually create the list in the question from things I saw in life data)

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu sql-server 2012 (just made sure I got the correct one. will put that info into the question also)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `LEAD` to look into following records.

```
select logdate, logentry
from
(
  select logdate, logentry, lead(logentry, 3) over (order by logdate) as logentry3
  from mytable
) t
where logentry3 = 'Tag';
```

Comment: order by date   should that mean order by "logdate"?

Answer (score 1):

Use of `lead` and `row_number()` are the way to go.  However, back in the days of the dinosaurs, I recall having read an article or two discussion how to work these problems, and decided to try to recreate how they did it (back then I was still struggling with `SELECT` statements). This will work, once you check over syntax for your tables:

```
SELECT
   base.LogEntry
  ,base.LogDate
  ,max(threeBack.LogDate)  ThreeBack
 from myTable base
  inner join myTable oneBack
   on oneBack.LogDate < base.LogDate
  inner join myTable twoBack
   on twoBack.LogDate < oneBack.LogDate
  inner join myTable threeBack
   on threeBack.LogDate < twoBack.LogDate
 where base.Type = 'Update'
 group by
   base.LogEntry
  ,base.LogDate
```

The general concept is:
 - For the datetime of each target row, find the first date prior to that
 - For that date, find it's prior date (two before)
 - Repeat, to get three before
 - Use group by, to (a) get the final values and (b) try and cover up the fact that you essentially just did 4 cross joins

Under the hood the SQL optimizer might be able to optimize how this is actually performed. I still recommend using the ranking-type functions; keep this around if you're stuck somewhere where you only have bone knives and bearskins to write your queries with.

Comment: How does it make sure that its always only the first date that is lower that is gotten (and not that oneback is in reality 2 back,...)?

Comment: Through the less-thans. Assume data is Jan 1-10, and the tag row is the 10th. Oneback will join on 1-9, TwoBack joins that to 1-8, ThreeBack joins *that* to 1-7, and you get max over ThreeBack to get 7. So, yes, you are group-bying across 10x9x8x7 = 5040 rows when you started with only 10, and you’re doing this for each “target” row (say, Jan 20 and Jan 30 as well, which gets you + 20x18x18x17 rows, etc. etc.). Unless the query engine is pretty clever (and has useful indexes), on large tables this will tank your server… which may be why MS broke down and added these Oracle functions.

Comment: I geuss with a few million entries inside the table the admins would be after my head if I used that one!  But interesting alternative all the less thus +1